# Connect android via Bluetooth to PlayStation4 controller and get some input from controller

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I am using as a reference (for bluetooth connecting), the bluez-ime code.
( https://code.google.com/p/android-bluez-ime/ )

I am Unable to successfully connect to a PS4 controller via bluetooth.
Has anyone been successful in doing that?
i keep getting connection refused when i look inside the logcat after socket.connect function.

Do i need a specific PS4 UUID for that? 
(tried the getUuids and fetchUuidsWithSdp to get the UUID of device, but wasn't successful..)

I Tried using the bluetoothviewer application (on play store) just to see if it's able to connect to the controller, but that doesn't work as well.

(just to clarify , the controller and the android device are paired and the controller's led lights are lit)

Any ideas?

Relevant part from `logcat`:

```
D/BluetoothViewer( 5799): onActivityResult -1
D/BluetoothChatService( 5799): connect to: 1C:66:6D:10:74:94
V/BluetoothSocket.cpp( 5799): initSocketNative
V/BluetoothSocket.cpp( 5799): ...fd 39 created (RFCOMM, lm = 26)
V/BluetoothSocket.cpp( 5799): initSocketFromFdNative
V/BluetoothSocket.cpp( 5799): initSocketNative
V/BluetoothSocket.cpp( 5799): ...fd 55 created (RFCOMM, lm = 26)
V/BluetoothSocket.cpp( 5799): initSocketFromFdNative
I/BluetoothChatService( 5799): BEGIN mConnectThread
D/BluetoothChatService( 5799): setState() 0 -> 2
E/BluetoothViewer( 5799): + ON RESUME +
V/BluetoothService.cpp(22186): stopDiscoveryNative
E/BluetoothService.cpp(22186): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
I/BluetoothPolicyService(22186): getBluetoothDataTransferAllowed 
I/BluetoothViewer( 5799): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 2
D/BluetoothPolicyService(22186): MDM: isProfileEnabled = true
V/BluetoothSocket.cpp( 5799): connectNative
V/BluetoothSocket.cpp( 5799): ...connect(55, RFCOMM) = 111 (errno 111)
W/System.err( 5799): java.io.IOException: Connection refused
W/System.err( 5799):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connectNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 5799):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:243)
W/System.err( 5799):    at net.bluetoothviewer.BluetoothChatService$ConnectThread.run(BluetoothChatService.java:244)
D/KeyguardViewMediator(22186): setHidden false
D/BluetoothChatService( 5799): setState() 2 -> 0
V/BluetoothSocket.cpp( 5799): abortNative
V/BluetoothSocket.cpp( 5799): ...asocket_abort(55) complete
V/BluetoothSocket.cpp( 5799): destroyNative
V/BluetoothSocket.cpp( 5799): ...asocket_destroy(55) complete
I/BluetoothViewer( 5799): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

PS4 controller uses HID profile to connect. But from above log of yours i see that its trying a RFCOMM connection. since HID sits on top of L2CAP and not RFCOMM, connection was refused.

If you are inclined to make an app, try initiating connect from HID service to complete HID connection.